# Music player widget title cut off

Tags: app-widgets, google-play-music

My iPod recently broke so I started using Google Play Music on my phone. It works quite well and today I discovered the widget, so I added it to my home screen. It's very useful, the only thing is that the title is cut off slightly and the whole widget seems too low. You can still clearly make out what it says but it just doesn't look very nice. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is a screenshot to explain it better:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the number of rows on the screen. On the screenshot in the question, there are six rows designated for shortcuts and widgets. If the number of rows is reduced to five the music widget comes out as it should:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>